# XtraTreeList CheckEdit Set Value?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtratreelist

I am using the DevExpress TreeList control, and have several columns which contain a Check Box, i.e. I have set the ColumnEdit property to a RepositoryCheckEdit.

How can I programatically set the value of these check boxes to True/False, for different nodes?

I have used the TreeListNode[index] = "string", for string columns, but can't do the same for the CheckEdit.

Thank you.

Comment: I know, I've changed it my workmate didn't realize she was editing another question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the following code:

TreeListNode[ColumnIndex] = true;

Please also refer to the [Obtaining and Setting Cell Values](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument191) topic.